# is O(N*M) O(N) or O(N^2)?

Tags: performance, caching, time-complexity, big-o

I'm looking at Mattson's Stack Distance Algorithm for finding the hit ratio curve for cache. The paper stated that it runs in O(N*M). I'm trying to figure out if this is O(N) or O(N^2).

Comment: If you disregard big-O part for a while, and just look at the expressions themselves, would you consider plain `N * M` to be equivalent to either `N` or `N * N` (assuming `N != M`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would say if `N` and `M` were the same number then `N * N`, but if not then `N`, is that right?

Comment: If N and M are both **not** constants, O(N*M) will never be the same as O(N).

Comment: @wohlstad "The algorithm runs in O(N ∗ M) time, where N is total number
of references and M is unique number of references. "

Comment: In that case, `O(N*M)` is neither `O(N)` or `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @StephenC so it's own thing or is it something else

Comment: It is its own thing.

Comment: Look ... if you want understand what big O notation really means, you have to **understand** the mathematics.   Go to your textbook or lecture notes from your "discrete maths" course and read the definition ...

Comment: @StephenC i didn't know it was more i thought it was just `O(n!)` `O(log n)` `O(1)` `O(n)` `O(n log n)` `O(n^2)` `O(2^n)`

Comment: Well yea ... that is why you need to understand the math.

Comment: This can be a place to start reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. Look for "Multiple variables" section. As mentioned above it is hard to get this issue right without the proper matehmatical background.

Comment: @wohlstad thanks i took calculus so this shouldn't be hard to understand

Comment: That is true.  Big O can be understood in terms of limits.  Limits are a basis for calculus too.